# Setting up MSVC compiler in Qt Creator

Tags: visual-c++, qt-creator

I recently downloaded Qt 5.3.2 for Windows 64 bit (offline installation). I installed it and when I ran a simple console program in the IDE, an error propped up saying that Qt Creator needs a compiler set up to build. Now how do I configure Qt Creator for compiling with MSVC 2013?

Comment: Could you edit thr question with the error you're getting? It will help narrow down your problem.

Comment: "Qt needs a compiler setup to build.configure a compiler in Kit options" Under the kits tab it is auto detecting the kit but it comes with a red stop sign. when i hover the cursor over it.. it says " error: no compiler set up warning: no debugger setup"

Comment: Oh pardon. What a lame error message on part of Qt.

Comment: Why don't you just install the full MSVC Qt SDK from `qt-project.org/downloads`(http://download.qt-project.org/official_releases/qt/5.3/5.3.2/qt-opensource-windows-x86-msvc2013_64_opengl-5.3.2.exe)?

Comment: I did just that.. but the compiler is not being detected.. msvc 2010 and 2012 have been auto detected. but msvc 2013 is not

Comment: @KausicGunasekkar Well, if you install `Qt MSVC 2013 64-bit 5.3.2` then you need to install `Microsoft Visual Studio 2013` which will come with the compiler. Your problem is that you don't have a MSVC compiler installed, that's why Qt doesn't find it. Because of license issues, Qt doesn't come bundled with MSVC.

Comment: @Kroltan What is so lame about the error message? It doesn't have a compiler setup, how could it be made more clearer?

Comment: @luliu thanks for your help. I really appreciate it. So all i need to do now is install visual studio 2013 right ? should i do anything else? and one more questions qt for windows 32 bit should work fine with a windows 64 bit system, right?